# jQuery: set height of <section> to height of all its children?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have this …

```
<section class="cat">
   <article class="layer"></article>
   <article class="layer"></article>
   <article class="layer"></article>
   <article class="layer"></article>
</section>

<section class="cat">
   <article class="layer"></article>
   <article class="layer"></article>
   <article class="layer"></article>
</section>
```

And I want to set the height of each `section.cat` to the height of all its children.
I wanna do this with jquery so I'm compatible in all browsers. It seems like there is no way to this with pure css as my `article.layer`s are set to `display:table`…

```
article.layer {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

So all articles are 100% the height of the current viewport as my `body` and `html` are set to 100% height as well.

Right now `section.cat` is set to `display:inline` which works in most browsers but doesn't in  Safari 5.0.

```
section.cat {
    display:inline;
}
```

So therefore I want to do this with jquery and get the height of each child inside `section.cat` and set its height to this value. Otherwise the height of `section.cat`s is 0 and as mentioned above Safari 5.0 somehow can't deal with the `display:inline` value.

Thank you!

Comment: Why does section.cat need to be inline if it's children are all 100% width and height?

Comment: So, you have ARTICLE elements that are `display:table` inside SECTION elements that are `display:inline`. Why?

Comment: And shouldn't sections be inside articles, not the other way around?

Comment: Can `display:inline` elements even have a height?

Comment: what other display-state is there to set `section.cat` to? I have all article elements set to `display:table` and 100% high and wide so each article has the exact size of the current browser viewport. Some of those articles are wrapped inside sections as you can see. When I do not set the sections to display:inline non of the articles inside are visible - they are simply not there because the height of the section is 0. If I apply `display:inline` it works just fine except for Safari 5.0. Any other suggestions how to do so?

Comment: Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/LW3bj/ If you uncomment the `display:inline` for the sections only 3 articles appear! If there is a pure css solution I'd like to hear it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to find css equivalent for to to solve but still if you want jQuery solution then here it is.

```
var totalHeight;
$(".cat").each(functon(){
   totalHeight = 0;
   $(this).children(".layer").each(function(){
      totalHeight += $(this).height();
   })
   $(this).height(totalHeight);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, do you maybe know a pure CSS way or is jquery the best solution for this … jsfiddle.net/LW3bj